# The Super User Blog -- now officially blessed!

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

Great job on the blog!

After a call today with Ivo, we decided that the Super User Blog is now *sufficiently awesome* to be highlighted in the footer! You'll note that the blog link **in the Super User footer** now points to

> http://blog.superuser.com/

And it will correctly update to flag [new] posts (or it should, anyway).

Contact Ivo if you have a proposal for a blog entry you'd like to write on some hardware or software topic you are passionate about.

<sub>Also, a little birdie told me that Ivo might be able to officially subsidize hardware purchases for the purposes of writing a great Super User blog entry about it...</sub>

Comment: Awesome[!](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com)

Comment: Shouldn't the "blog" link in the footer of *this* very Meta site also link to that same site then?

Comment: @arjan ok that is done!

Answer (score 13):

I want to thank @ThomasMcDonald for getting the site together and doing all the background stuff.  Also thanks to all of you for your input and suggestions for posts!  And finally, thanks Jeff for your tweets :P

[image]

Comment: let's not forget: **KUDOS** to KronoS for his work with the blog!  He deserves a tshirt!

Comment: Congratulations All!  How long was the blog running before this turning point where it took off and skyrocketed?  How many people in the community can write blog articles?  I'm asking because I was thinking about something similar for other SE sites.

Comment: @jmort253 We're already working on getting the other SE sites up and running as well.  If you have interest then pop into the [SE Blog Chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs) and "ping" @JeffAtwood, @RebeccaChernoff, or @ThomasMcDonald.  They'll be able to keep you up to date on their status.  As far as our blog you can suggest ideas there, or even write up articles to be submitted for review.  Again for more info pop into the chat and talk to either me (@Kronos) or @IvoFlipse.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll monitor communications in that room :)