# One-boxing on Super User chat for the SU Blog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, superuser-blog, chat

Now that the SU blog [is official](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2153/the-super-user-blog-now-officially-blessed), it would be nice if posts from the SU blog could be one-boxed in Chat, like posts from the official SO blog are. Could this be enabled? I imagine it would be a pretty trivial code change, as both blogs are running on the same platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could!  Also, @balpha rocks. (:

Comment: +1 for neutral journalism

Comment: Thanks very much, @balpha and @Rebecca!